# Sorting in stackbar and/or cross table with TOP 10 and "Other"

Tags: expression, spotfire

I made a cross table and an stackbar, with a Top 10 rankging and a group over 10, withe the following expression:

```
If(DenseRank(Sum([Balance]) OVER ([Countries]),"desc")<=10,[Countries],"Other") as [Countries]
```

This works very fine in both results. But now I have the problem, that "Other" should be shown after the TOP 10 result and at the end of the stackbar. At the moment I have only the possiblity to sort it by Country Name or Balance.

Do you have an answer for my question?

Kind regards,

Kai

Tibco Spotfire Analyst 7.14.0

```
If(DenseRank(Sum([Balance]) OVER ([Countries]),"desc")<=10,[Countries],"Other") as [Countries]
```

I need the correct ranking: 1-10 and then "Other" for the last stack and row.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a problem like this in the past. I found that adding a leading space to the country name 'cheats' the sort order.

```
If(DenseRank(Sum([Balance]) OVER ([Countries]),"desc")<=10,Concatenate(" ",[Countries]),"Other") as [Countries]
```

Comment: thx, but the result is the same :(, my sorting category is VALUE not alphabetic :)

Comment: Not possible to sort by value and category in my experience. You could get a little creative and include the value ranking in the category. This should work, for example   `If(DenseRank(Sum([Balance]) OVER ([Countries]),"desc")<=10,Concatenate(Repeat(" ",DenseRank(Sum([Balance]) OVER ([Countries]),"asc")),[Countries]),"Other")`

Comment: Thx, now "Other" is at the end of the bar chart, but in front of "Other" its not in the Top 10 order .... is there anyway to get this result?